# I can't delete the html tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to remove the Placemark tag so that I can replace it with a Placemark with a different picture. This event should occur when you click on the image. React error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')

```
import React from "react";
import './SearchPower.css';
import { YMaps, Map, Placemark} from '@pbe/react-yandex-maps';

function App() {
  // Определение геопозиции пользователя 
  var getLocationPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async function (position) {
    resolve([position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude])
    })
  })
    var [lat, setLat] = React.useState(0)
    var [lng, setLng] = React.useState(0)
  getLocationPromise.then((location) => {
    setLat(location[0])
    setLng(location[1])
  })
  if (lat == 0 && lng == 0) {
    lat = 55.75
    lng = 37.57 }

    

  // Создание карты
  var myMap = React.useMemo(
    () => ({ center: [lat, lng], zoom: 9 })
  );
  
  // Работа с метками
  var IconGeoPosition = "images/Marks/ZemMark.png"
  function GeoPositionMarkChanged(LinkMark) {
    IconGeoPosition = LinkMark
    ChangedMyPosition()
  }

  function ChangedMyPosition() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myPosition");
    elem.removeChild(elem); // THE ERROR OCCURS HERE.

    return <Placemark geometry={[lat, lng]} 
    options={{
      iconLayout: 'default#image',
      iconImageHref: IconGeoPosition,
      iconImageSize: [40, 40],
      iconImageOffset: [100, -10]
    }} className="myPosition"/>;
  }
  
    return (
      <div className="ContextSP">
        <div className="DivMarks">
        <img className="MarkLeftImage" src="images/Marks/ZemMark.png" onClick={function() {GeoPositionMarkChanged("images/Marks/ZemMark.png")}}/>
        <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/Redcar1Mark.png" onClick={function() {GeoPositionMarkChanged("images/Marks/Redcar1Mark.png")}}/>
        <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/Redcar2Mark.png" onClick={function() {GeoPositionMarkChanged("images/Marks/Redcar2Mark.png")}}/>
        <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/GreencarMark.png" onClick={function() {GeoPositionMarkChanged("images/Marks/GreencarMark.png")}}/>
        <img className="MarkRightImage" src="images/Marks/YellowcarMark.png" onClick={function() {GeoPositionMarkChanged("images/Marks/YellowcarMark.png")}}/>
        </div>
          <YMaps>
          <Map style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', margin: '0 0 10px 0'}} state={myMap}>
              <Placemark geometry={[lat, lng]} 
                  options={{
                    iconLayout: 'default#image',
                    iconImageHref: IconGeoPosition,
                    iconImageSize: [40, 40],
                    iconImageOffset: [100, -10]
                  }} id="myPosition"></Placemark>
          </Map>
          </YMaps>
        </div>
        )
    }
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `removeChild` is the wrong approach here. You're breaking out of React to change the DOM manually, which goes against what React is doing for you. This isn't the reason this code fails (that's most likely because the `Placemark` component doesn't do anything with the `id` prop, so it's never passed to the actual DOM elements being rendered), but it is an inherent flaw in the way you're trying to achieve this. What you **want** is to use state for the `imageHref`:

```
// ...
const [imageHref, setImageHref] = React.useState("images/Marks/ZemMark.png");

function changeGeoPosition(newLink) {
    setImageHref(newLink);
}

return (
  <div className="ContextSP">
    <div className="DivMarks">
      <img className="MarkLeftImage" src="images/Marks/ZemMark.png" onClick={function() {changeGeoPosition("images/Marks/ZemMark.png")}}/>
      <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/Redcar1Mark.png" onClick={function() {changeGeoPosition("images/Marks/Redcar1Mark.png")}}/>
      <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/Redcar2Mark.png" onClick={function() {changeGeoPosition("images/Marks/Redcar2Mark.png")}}/>
      <img className="MarkImage" src="images/Marks/GreencarMark.png" onClick={function() {changeGeoPosition("images/Marks/GreencarMark.png")}}/>
      <img className="MarkRightImage" src="images/Marks/YellowcarMark.png" onClick={function() {changeGeoPosition("images/Marks/YellowcarMark.png")}}/> 
    </div>
    <YMaps>
      <Map style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', margin: '0 0 10px 0'}} state={myMap}>
        <Placemark geometry={[lat, lng]} 
          options={{
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: imageHref,
            iconImageSize: [40, 40],
            iconImageOffset: [100, -10]
        }}/>
      </Map>
    </YMaps>
  </div>
)
```

React's `useState` hook and other state-managing mechanisms will do all the dirty rendering (like `element.removeChild`) **for you**. It's incredibly rare that you'll need to use the native DOM in such a way when using React.